# Compiler Construction for Pascal - detect float number and array format

Tags: compiler-construction, lexical-analysis, finite-automata

I want to construct a compiler for pseudo-pascal language. We learn compiler principles and we learn about scanner (lexical analyzer). We construct a DFA for our scanner, then convert it to a switch based code and generate code for that DFA to read our file. We have a problem in pseudo-pascal language.
our float numbers are in this format: `d+.` or `d*.d+` so `1.` or `.25` are float numbers.
the format of array declaration is something like this: `array[1 .. 25] of integer`
until there is space between numbers and `..` in array declaration, there is no problem, however, in this language we can write it like `1..25`. the problem arise because our DFA match `1.` and `.25` as two float numbers!!!
Our teacher ask us a question to how to solve this with changing our DFA and scanner code.
**Note: We don't want to change parser code and parser need 3 tokens (integer .. integer) for array. so we must return 3 tokens for array and return one token if it is a real number. (not a number in array declaration)**

I read a lot of pages about compiler and I see a something like backtracking for solve this problem. However I think our teacher didn't want that way based on something that I ask from him.
I think a lot and try different way. The only thing that I can do is to change code and use something like memory to remember that I have read `.` extra or put back `.` in file stream for later scanning or change file pointer to solve problem.
I want to sure that there is no way to solve this problem with changing in DFA? Is the way that I mentioned are the only way??
I'm sorry for bad English.
Is is possible to help me? Thanks.

Comment: See the trailing context syntax `r/s` in the [flex patterns documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)

Comment: I couldn't find that. can you give a link and explain what is `r/s`? I ask problem generally and not for flex only however I couldn't find what you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, must have pasted the wrong URL. Here's the one I meant: http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html. You can search that page for the string `r/s`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the logic in such a way that after seeing `[` in an array declaration (and before seeing the corresponding `]`) you can only expect integer numbers, which implies that you need to have a way of parsing integer constants that does not try to parse real values ones.

IOW, in arbitrary expressions (e.g. `a := <expression>`) you do want to be able to parse all kinds of constants, but in array declarations you want to use a parser restricted to integers.